# maximum recursion depth exceeded requests

Tags: python, django, python-3.x, wagtail

Currently new to python/django so forgive me if this is a simple question.

I am using requests to download a json file and am trying to parse/display the values in a template.

I receive the following error:
`maximum recursion depth exceeded while calling a Python object

Code is below:

```
from django import template
from django.template.loader import render_to_string
from wagtail.wagtailcore.blocks.base import Block
from django.http import HttpResponse
from django.shortcuts import render
from django.template import loader

import datetime
import urllib
import json
import requests
import requests_cache

requests_cache.install_cache('demo_cache')

register = template.Library()

# Advert snippets
@register.inclusion_tag('swd/templates/adverts.html', takes_context=True)
def adverts(context):
    return {
        'adverts': Advert.objects.all(),
        'request': context['request'],
    }

#Socialboard
#Pinterest
@register.inclusion_tag('blocks/socialboard.html')
def get_pinterest_pins():
    req = requests.get(URL)
    req_json = json.loads(req.content)

    for key, value in req_json.items():
        print (key, value)

# Related within article
@register.filter
def inject_related_after_paragraph(value, arg):
    related_list = render_to_string("related.list.html")
    paragraphs = value.split('</p>')

    if arg < len(paragraphs):
        paragraphs[arg] = related_list + paragraphs[arg]
        value = '</p>'.join(paragraphs)
    return value

@register.filter
def inject_advert_after_paragraph(value, arg):
    advert = render_to_string("adverts.html")
    paragraphs = value.split('</p>')

    if arg < len(paragraphs):
        paragraphs[arg] = advert + paragraphs[arg]
        value = '</p>'.join(paragraphs)

    return value
```

This loops through the URL ok but continously until a point that it times out.

Comment: quote in the end of the third line might cause the problem

Comment: Provide URL, so we can test and confirm.

Comment: Please format your code correctly, and post complete traceback.

Comment: @Rachitkapadia A quote causing a recursion error?

Comment: Not sure, but I'd guess the JSON is too deeply nested.

Comment: @Chris_Rands It will cause the syntax error

Comment: Note: If you are looking to convert response object into json, then it already have `json` method attribute. ie, `req.json()`

Comment: The third line quote was a type @Rachitkapadia. Apologies.

Answer (score 1):

The following code perfectly works:

```
import requests
import json

req = requests.get('https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts/1')
req_json = json.loads(req.content)

for key, value in req_json.items():
    print (key, value)
```

Depending on the URL, the resulting JSON could be "too deeply nested". 
If the error occurred on `json.loads`, you'll have to find a JSON decoder that uses a stack instead of recursive calls. If the error occurred on the `print` statement, avoid printing that dictionary (or define your own function that uses a stack instead).

Comment: What would happen if it was "too deeply nested"?

Comment: Assuming that json.loads implementation is based on recursive calls, then Python will hit its maximal recursive call depth when the depth of the structure is greater than the predefined recursive call limit. You can increase this limit using `sys.setrecursionlimit(10000)` for example, but I do not suggest to do that (consider looking at http://neopythonic.blogspot.be/2009/04/tail-recursion-elimination.html).

Comment: Ok. I ran the code you have above and also experience the same issue with maximum recursion depth. Must be calling itself somewhere but just not sure where.

Comment: If you used the same URL than the one I provided and have an error, that means there is something wrong in your way of calling this code. Please update your initial question with that code, or open a new question. For instance, the code you showed us in your initial post doesn't call the ´get_pinterest_pins` function, so I assume something is missing there.

Comment: I have update the original code to give a full view of the file. Ultimately, the function should output the result to the template.

Comment: I don't think one can print in a tag. I don't see either where URL is set.

Comment: Do you mean the requests url? Sorry, new to python programming.

Comment: Exactly, I don't see where the variable URL is defined. I think the problem you got is not necessarily related to the initial piece of code you provided...

Comment: Apologies the "URL" is a placeholder for the actual URL. Didn't want to reveal that publicly.

Comment: Did you try to request that URL in a separate script to isolate the problem?